# Spark OutOfMemory Error is remedied by repartition

Tags: apache-spark, out-of-memory, gzip, parquet

I have highly compressed non-splittable gzip archive ~100MB size and ~10 mln records. I'm trying to read it into spark dataframe and then write it to parquet. I have one driver and one executor (16GB RAM, 8vCPU, in fact, it's a Glue job with 2 G1.X nodes).

Read gzipped CSV / write parquet directly leads to OOM:

```
df = spark.read.option("sep", "|") \
    .option("header", "true") \
    .option("quote", "\"") \
    .option("mode", "FAILFAST") \
    .csv("path.gz")
    

df.write
    .format("parquet") \
    .mode("Overwrite") \
    .save("path")
```

And I can understand this. DataFrame is loaded into single executor memory, it doesn't fit and OOM appears. But, if call `.repartition(8)` (same hardware setup) before write, then everything is OK, no OOM occurred. I don't understand why this happens, anyway we have to load all DataFrame into executor memory?

Comment: the reason is, when spark reads gzip, it will return the dataframe with one partition, you can repartition(n) after reading or when you read csv itself, you can give how many partitions.

Comment: and each executor can execute the partitions parallel, based on number of cores, so if you have 8 cores, it can execute all 8 partitions parallel.

Comment: I understand this. But still don't why OOM doesn't appear with repartition